# Having issues reading the contents of my array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i have this text based game and I am making a prompt where the user has to enter in some text and based on what options are given a specific function is executed. however, when the code reads the length of the array, it says the array is undefined. heres the code:

```
//handles user input
function uiPrompt (options) {
    for (var i = 0; i < options[0].length; ++i) {
        if (playerInput = options[i][0]) {break; }
        options[i][0];
    }
}

//start menu at the beginning of the game
function startMenu () {
    options = [ ['n', 'l', 'new game', 'load game', 'new', 'load'],
                    ['newGame()', 'loadGame()', 'newGame()', 'loadGame()', 'newGame()', 'loadGame()'] ];
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'RANDOM RPG: Where everything is random! \n (N)ew Game \n (L)oad Game';
    uiPrompt();
}
```

so in the options variable the first row are the strings of user input the code will accept as valid player choices. The adjacent elements just below each option element in the first row are the functions to be executed when the corresponding choice is entered. For example, if the player was to type 'n' to start a new game, then the element right below it, function newGame() would be executed. My issue is when the submit user input button is pressed (which calls the uiPrompt function) I get the error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined for this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < options[0].length; ++i) {
```

what am I doing wrong? thanx in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are not passing the options array into your function, which make it inaccessible to the uiPromt function. It should be uiPromt(options). I hope you have assigned you options variable somewhere, otherwise options would be set as a global variable and it could cause problems later on.

Comment: I set options as a global variable, i just didn't put it in my question

Comment: you are still passing an empty parameter called options into you argument. Pass you array into you uiPromt function by calling uiPromt(options) in your startMenu function. Does this make sense?

Comment: Have a look at this : http://jsbin.com/heqoyeyaco/1/edit, it should make more sense. If you dont pass the parameter into the function when you call it, it will be deemed undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are calling uiPrompt without the option argument
try:

```
function startMenu () {
    options = [ ['n', 'l', 'new game', 'load game', 'new', 'load'],
                    ['newGame()', 'loadGame()', 'newGame()', 'loadGame()', 'newGame()', 'loadGame()'] ];
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'RANDOM RPG: Where everything is random! \n (N)ew Game \n (L)oad Game';
    uiPrompt(options); // rather then uiPrompt()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant store function calls as strings in an array when you want to call them.
(Well you could somehow but that would be evel)

maybe do something like

```
var options: {
  newGame:  ['n', 'new game', 'game'],
  loadGame: ['l', 'load game', 'game']
}
var functions: {
  newGame: function() {
    /* your function */
  },
  loadGame: function() {
    /* your function */
  }
}
```

Then in uiPromt you could do

```
for (functionName in options) {
  // check if playerInput is in options[functionName] array
  if (options[functionName].indexOf(playerInput) >= 0) {
    functions[functionName]() // call function
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: what am I supposed to replace functionName with?

Comment: plus I plan on calling to the uiPrompt throughout the game and there wont always be just two functions to choose from to be executed. For example, I might include a scenario later on in the game where they can choose three different choices that will trigger three different functions or maybe five or maybe twenty!

Comment: you dont need to replace it. it is a variable it will contain `newGame` or `loadGame`

Comment: can you show me an example of what the entire script would look like with your revisions?

Comment: You can call any number of functions inside any function so replace /* your function */ with function calls… as an alternative you could select your functions with a switch statement

Comment: Yes!!!! I got it to work! I just had to change functions and options to global variables, include them in the button onclick function and change the colons to equal signs. thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Just updated you js and you had some errors init so I corrected them. Just console logging the values in uiPromt, is this what you want to achieve?

```
//used for ui to determine in certain prompts which commands are acceptable
    var options = [];
    //the input that the player puts in the ui box
    var playerInput;

    //handles user input
    function uiPrompt () {
        playerInput = document.getElementById("prompt").value;
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
            if (playerInput == options[i][0]) {break; }
            console.log(options[i][0]);
        }
    }

    //start menu at the beginning of the game
    function startMenu () {
        options = [ ['n', 'l', 'new game', 'load game', 'new', 'load'],
                        ['newGame()', 'loadGame()', 'newGame()', 'loadGame()', 'newGame()', 'loadGame()'] ];
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'RANDOM RPG: Where everything is random! \n (N)ew Game \n (L)oad Game';
    }

    //the new game menu
    function newGame () {
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'You started a new game.';
    }

    startMenu();
```